# New row not visible in Maximo

Tags: maximo

I have a requirement to add row on a tab which does not exist by OOB. Hence in order to achieve this I mapped psdi.webclient.system.beans.DataBean  bean class to the table and then added new row button. Now on click of new row button the new row doesn't show however when I click on "there is no rows to display" then the newly added row is displayed.

```html
<tab id="actuals_actuals_acservices" label="Services">
       <table id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table" label="Services" relationship="SHOWACTUALSERVICE">
        <tablebody displayrowsperpage="6" filterable="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_tablebody">
         <tablecol filterable="false" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_tablebody_1" mxevent="toggledetailstate" mxevent_desc="Show Detail" sortable="false" type="event"/>
         <tablecol dataattribute="actualstaskid" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_tablebody_2" linkedcontrolid="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid7_1" sortable="false"/>
         <tablecol dataattribute="itemnum" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_tablebody_3" label="Service" rechover="item_recordhover"/>
         <tablecol dataattribute="description" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_tablebody_4" lookup="longdesc"/>
         <tablecol dataattribute="quantity" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_tablebody_5" linkedcontrolid="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid8_1"/>
         <tablecol dataattribute="unitcost" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_tablebody_6" linkedcontrolid="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid8_2"/>
         <tablecol dataattribute="loadedcost" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_tablebody_7" linkedcontrolid="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid8_3"/>
         <tablecol filterable="false" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_tablebody_8" mxevent="toggledeleterow" mxevent_desc="Mark Row for Delete" mxevent_icon="btn_garbage.gif" sortable="false" type="event"/>
        </tablebody>
        <tabledetails id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1">
         <section id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_sec1" label="Details">
          <sectionrow id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_sec1row1">
           <sectioncol id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_sec1row1_1">
            <section id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid7">
             <textbox dataattribute="actualstaskid" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid7_1" inputmode="readonly" sizeintable="4"/>
             <combobox dataattribute="linetype" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid7_3"/>
             <multiparttextbox dataattribute="itemnum" descdataattribute="description" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid7_2" inputmode="readonly" label="Service" longdescreadonly="true" rechover="item_recordhover"/>
            </section>
           </sectioncol>
           <sectioncol id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_sec1row1_2">
            <section id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid8">
             <textbox dataattribute="quantity" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid8_1" inputmode="readonly" sizeintable="9"/>
             <textbox dataattribute="unitcost" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid8_2" inputmode="readonly"/>
             <textbox dataattribute="poline.orderunit" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid8_5" inputmode="readonly"/>
             <textbox dataattribute="loadedcost" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid8_3" inputmode="readonly"/>
             <textbox dataattribute="transdate" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid8_4" inputmode="readonly"/>
            </section>
           </sectioncol>
           <sectioncol id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_sec1row1_3">
            <section id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid10">
             <textbox dataattribute="gldebitacct" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid10_1" inputmode="readonly" lookup="glnavigator"/>
             <textbox dataattribute="glcreditacct" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid10_2" inputmode="readonly" lookup="glnavigator"/>
             <textbox applink="po" dataattribute="ponum" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid10_5" inputmode="readonly" menutype="normal"/>
             <textbox dataattribute="polinenum" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid10_6" inputmode="readonly"/>
             <textbox dataattribute="enterby" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid10_3" inputmode="readonly"/>
             <textbox dataattribute="enterdate" dynamic="true" id="actuals_actuals_acservices_acservices_table_1_grid10_4" inputmode="readonly"/>
            </section>
           </sectioncol>
          </sectionrow>
         </section>
        </tabledetails>        
       </table>
      </tab>
```

This is basically the actuals tab services section in work order . I see that it works in other instance but for some reason not in the particular instance that I'm working on. The record gets saved in the DB however it's not coming up in the UI
[image: add row]

Comment: What are your parent and child objects and what is the relationship used? Can you post the actual XML?

Comment: @JPTremblay updated the tab XML,